# Show one part & hide another part

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to hide one dive with ✓ (sign in part) & show another div with remove ✓ (sign up part) on my login page.
I used from ng-if & run show part; but I don't know how hide another part at the same time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<b>

    <body ng-app="" bgcolor="#f0f8ff">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="pwd-container">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <section class="login-form"></section>
                <form method="post" action="#" role="login">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="form-control input-lg" value="joestudent@gmail.com" />

                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />


                    <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>


                    <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                    <div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
            </div>

            New User? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar" ng-init="myVar = false">
            <div ng-if="myVar">


                <form action="action_page.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                        <hr>

                        <label><b>Email</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                        <label><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                        <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
                        </label>

                        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr>
                <br>
            </div>

    </body>
</b>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to reverse the condition for the login form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" role="login" ng-if="!myVar">
  .....
</form>
```

`ng-if` means show the element when the value is true. In your case you want to show the login form when (not new user) (`!myVar`)

Answer (score 0):

Just add ng-if="!myVar" to the login section

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<b>

    <body ng-app="" bgcolor="#f0f8ff">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="pwd-container">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>

            <div class="col-md-4" ng-if="!myVar">
                <section class="login-form"></section>
                <form method="post" action="#" role="login">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="form-control input-lg" value="joestudent@gmail.com" />

                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />


                    <div class="pwstrength_viewport_progress"></div>


                    <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                    <div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
            </div>

            New User? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar" ng-init="myVar = false">
            <div ng-if="myVar">


                <form action="action_page.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                        <hr>

                        <label><b>Email</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                        <label><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                        <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
                        </label>

                        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <button   class="cancelbtn"  ng-click="myVar = !myVar" >Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr>
                <br>
            </div>

    </body>
</b>

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.